# Nokogirl scraping talk from AudioDharma page

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Here is my code:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://feeds.feedburner.com/audiodharma"))
talks = doc.css(".regularitem")
```

The css seems pretty straightforward, so I can't figure out why I keeping getting an empty array for 'talks'. Let me know if you see something I'm not-- Nokogiri beginner here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use `cURL` or another method to fetch the content directly, you will see your XML starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" media="screen" href="/~d/styles/rss2enclosuresfull.xsl"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~d/styles/itemcontent.css"?>
<rss xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:creativeCommons="http://backend.userland.com/creativeCommonsRssModule" xmlns:feedburner="http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0" version="2.0">
    ...
```

As you can see, it's an XML file and not an HTML file. I'm not sure why, but Nokogiri doesn't know how to handle it properly when trying to open the URI **by itself** - it's an XML with some styling properties for browsers. It reads fine usually, I'm not sure about the specs more in depth.

One solution I found was to load the URL using `RestClient` and once the content loaded it was parsed properly. Also you should call Nokogiri's `XML` and call it by its name. Then the search by CSS method works without a problem:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(RestClient.get("https://feeds.feedburner.com/audiodharma"))
doc.css('.regularitem') # => has valid Nokogiri output
```